# How to disable .htaccess redirect for a specific folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirection

I write the following `.htaccess` rules to redirect all URLs from `www.a.com` to `www.b.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.a.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^a.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.b.com/myfolder/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

Now there is a file under a subdir of `a.com`, as below:

```
www.a.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/#######
```

It is used for AutoSSL renewal. With the above redirection, the AutoSSL will not be able to find the file any more, so fail the renewal.

So, is it possible to disable the redirect under `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are redirecting everything to a fixed URL-path you might as well build the exception directly in the `RewriteRule` directive (there is no need to capture the URL-path as you are currently doing).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^\.well-known/acme-challenge/ https://www.b.com/myfolder/ [R=301,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* negates the expression, so it is successful when the regex does *not* match. In this case when the requested URL-path does not start `.well-known/acme-challenge/`. (However, see the "edge case" below.)

I also combined your two *conditions* (`RewriteCond` directives) into one. There is no need for the `NC` flag on the rule itself (assuming you are on Linux, not Windows).

Remember to backslash-escape literal dots in the regex.

#### Edge case (Optional extra)

Note that if you also have a front-controller pattern later in the `.htaccess` file (eg. WordPress, Joomla, most other frameworks/CMS, etc.) then you should also add a *condition* to the above rule to prevent rewrites to the front-controller being redirected when requesting a URL of the form `/.well-known/acme-challenge/<non-existent-file>`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
:
```

Without this condition then a request for `http://a.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/<non-existent-file>` would otherwise be redirected to `https://www.b.com/index.php` (assuming `index.php` is the front-controller).

#### Summary

The complete rule would then become:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?a\.com [NC]
RewriteRule !^\.well-known/acme-challenge/ https://www.b.com/myfolder/ [R=301,L]

# Front-controller pattern follows...
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> if the redirect is a simple line: `redirect 301 / https://www.b.com/myfolder/`, how to write the exception for `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`?

Since the *simple* `Redirect` (mod_alias) directive itself does not provide the ability to make "exceptions", you would need to surround the directive in an `<If>` expression (requires Apache 2.4). For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/#">
    Redirect 301 / https://www.b.com/myfolder/
</If>
```

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

(If you are using the `Redirect` directive like this then there is no "front-controller" pattern and no "edge case" as mentioned above.)

*Aside:* Whilst they might look similar, this `Redirect` directive is quite different to the `RewriteRule` directive used earlier and produces different results. The `RewriteRule` directive above *discards* the requested URL-path, redirecting everything to `https://www.b.com/myfolder/`. However, the `Redirect` directive used here *preserves* the requested URL-path, prefixing the URL-path with `/myfolder` (eg. `/foo/bar` is redirected to `https://www.b.com/myfolder/foo/bar`)

Comment: Thank you very much. Just another question, if the redirect is a simple line: ```redirect 301 / https://www.b.com/myfolder/```, how to write the exception for /.well-known/acme-challenge/?

Comment: @alancc You would need to use an `<If>` expression. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the leading "m#" and the trailing "#" is not regular expression?

Comment: @alancc The `m#...#` syntax are the "alternative" _delimiters_ for regular expressions in Apache expressions. See [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#other) I linked to above. I used the "alternative" syntax to avoid having to backslash-escape the literal slashes in the regex itself. Are you getting an error? (Personally, I would change this to use mod_rewrite instead. Apache `<If>` expressions change the order of processing and directives inside the `<If>` block are not always processed as expected.)

Comment: It works, but I wonder why it is not something like m#^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.*#", I add .* at the end of the regular expression as there are more contents after challeng/

Comment: The regex expression `.*` mean 'any character' zero o more times. If it appear at the start or end of a larger expression, it is effectively irrelevant, because the posible text they match (any characters before or any characters after) could be there (more times) or not (zero times) and match in both cases.

Comment: @alancc As Fjor said. We don't need to _match_ the whole URL-path, we just need to assert that the URL-path does not "start with" `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`. (Adding `.*` to the end just makes the regex marginally less efficient as it now needs to _unnecessarily_ traverse the entire string/URL-path.) And the same goes for the regex in your question... `^(.*)$` could be simplified to just `^`, which is more efficient for several reasons, as you simply need the rule to be successful for every URL-path, you don't need to actually _match_ anything.